# How can I temporarily map a remote host and port to a local port?

Tags: port-forwarding, netcat

Say I have a machine **A** acting as a router with two NICs and the following IP addresses:

```
eth0: 192.168.1.1 (LAN)
eth1: 10.0.0.1 (WAN)
```

And I have another machine **B** on IP address *10.0.0.2* that I want to be able to temporarily reach into a device on machine **A's** subnet with IP address *192.168.1.10*.

This would need to handle multiple connections over the same port (like an HTTP session), rather than just a one off.  I know of how to do this with SSH but I was wondering if there was a simpler alternative because in this scenario I'm already logged into machine A.

This is the SSH template I use for a similar scenario, when I'm not already logged in:

```
ssh -R 0:lanhost:lanport username@wanhost
```

The closest I've been able to get is this with netcat:

```
nc -s 10.0.0.1 -l -p 50000 -e /tmp/srv.sh
```

/tmp/srv.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
nc 192.168.1.10 80
```

But that only handles a single connection and creating the shell script is clunky.

NOTE: I'd rather not mess with the IP tables of machine **A** if possible.